# aligning one textview with the other in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

As the layout of a recyclerview I've one text view next to another (horizontal).  I have both textviews nested inside a linear layout.  I've set both textviews to expand their height to accommodate a text wrap.  What I need is to have both textviews height expand when only one requires it. Is there a configuration with my current layout that will accomplish this.

Here is my xml:

```
<Linearlayout
    android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation: Horizontal>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have horizontal orientation for the LinearLayout you must set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the views if you give them weights and not `android:layout_height="0dp"`. I made some changes:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity attribute for aligning textviews - Here is your expected code.

```
<Linearlayout
            android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Your text goes here."
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Your text goes here."
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </Linearlayout>
```